# Ubuntu 10.04 update GCC 4.8.1 to GCC 4.8.2

Tags: 10.04, gcc, g++

I installed GCC on Ubuntu 10.04 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

When I type:

```
g++ --version
```

I get:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2uubntu1~10.04.1) 4.8.1
```

**How do I update to version 4.8.2?**

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc* /usr/bin/g++*
`?

Answer (score 0):

The repository you have added (probably [this one](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-gcc-4-8-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-12-04-13-04/)) has GCC 4.8.1 only. You can either find a repository which provides GCC 4.8.2 for Ubuntu 10.04, compile it from source, or upgrade to 14.04.